# Обработка сигналов

Tags: c

Помогите поправить программу, выдающую на экран содержимое файла порциями по N строк; каждая последующая порция выдается после нажатия клавиш <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd>. Имя файла и величина `N` задаются в командной строке.
Вот мой код:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
int N,f1;

void a(int n){
    char c;
    while(N){
        read(f1,&c,1);
        if(c=='\n')
            N--;
        write(1,&c,1);
    }
}

int main (int argc,char **argv){
    signal(SIGINT,&a);
    N=atoi(argv[2]);
    f1=open(argv[1],O_RDONLY);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Зачем ее править, если она работает?

Comment: Она не правильно работает

Comment: И вы, конечно же, предлагаете угадать в чем же заключается "неправильно", на каких данных оно проявляется и так далее?

Comment: Я не знаю как решить эту задачу.Надеялся на помошь.А неправильность(ошибок нет,код ничего не делает так как никогда не получает сигнал) видна любому кто изучал C

Comment: Читать `read()`-ом по одному байту -- это просто издевательство. Читайте блоками, например по 4096 байт (весьма распространенная величина блока в файловой системе) и при поиске `\n` считайте байты. После вывода своих N строк сделайте `lseek()` в точку за последним найденным '\n'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После open программа сразу завершается и не ждет сигналов. предлагаю сделать переменную-флаг `FLAG=1` и после open в main `while(FLAG) { sleep(100); }` В обработчике сигнала, когда данных для вывода больше нет просто устанавливаете `FLAG=0`. sleep будет прерван сигналом так что цикл тут же завершится.

И после `while(N)` надо бы N опять делать равной аргументу, что бы читать следующую порцию строк при следующем сигнале. А внутри цикла, `read` вернет 0 когда файл закончится и тогда собственно `FLAG=0; break;`

Answer (score 0):

В *nix есть много способов дождаться сигнала (только помните, что сигналы не накапливаются), но пожалуй простейшим является вызов системной функции [pause](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pause).

Печать файла может происходить как внутри обработчика сигналов (асинхронно к основному потоку (не в смысле *thread*!) управления), так и синхронно, сразу после возврата из `pause`.

Учтите, что при программировании обработчика сигналов можно использовать ограниченный набор функций, а именно, так называемые *signal safe functions* (они перечислены в [man signal 7](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) (кстати, вместе с SEE_ALSO в нем вообще очень полезный для понимания системы man)).
Обратите внимание, что среди них нет ни функций работающих с `FILE \*` (fopen/fgets/fprintf/...), ни с динамическим распределением памяти (malloc/free/strdup...).
Аналогичные средства C++ (new, <<, >> и т.п.) тоже использовать нельзя.

Вот как может выглядеть программа, реализующая печать очередных N строк из заданного файла при нажатии в терминале ^C. (Практически вся обработка ошибок для простоты опущена). Тут представлены оба варианта печати, задаваемые переменной времени компиляции `NOUSE_HANDLER`.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <iostream>
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <err.h>

#define MESSAGE "\n--- no more data ---\n"
#define NLINES 20

#ifndef NOUSE_HANDLER  
volatile 
#endif
int fd, N = NLINES, stop = 0;

void 
pri_bysig (int sig)
{
#ifndef NOUSE_HANDLER  
  char buf[4096];
  int i, l, n = 0;
  off_t pos = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR);

  do {
    if ((l = read(fd, buf, 4096)) > 0) {
      for (i = 0; i < l && n < N; i++, pos++) 
        if (buf[i] == '\n')
          n++;
      write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, i);
    } else {
      write(STDOUT_FILENO, MESSAGE, sizeof(MESSAGE) - 1);
      stop = 1;
      break;
    } 
  } while (n < N);

  if (!stop)
    lseek(fd, pos, SEEK_SET);
#endif
}

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  if (av[1]) {
    if ((N = atoi(av[1])) < 1)
      N = NLINES;
    av++;
  }
  char *name = av[1] ? av[1] : (char *)__FILE__;
  fd = open(name, O_RDONLY);
  if (fd < 0)
    err(1, "can't open %s", name);
  signal(SIGINT, pri_bysig);

#ifdef NOUSE_HANDLER
  FILE *f = fdopen(fd, "r");
#endif

  do {
    puts("Gooo!");
    pause();
#ifdef NOUSE_HANDLER
    int n = 0, c;
    while ((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF && n < N) {
      putchar(c);
      if (c == '\n')
        n++;
    }
    if (c == EOF) {
      fputs(MESSAGE, stdout);
      stop = 1;
    }
#endif
  } while (!stop);

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

При вызове `gcc -DNOUSE_HANDLER ...` реализуется синхронная версия (обратите внимание, что обработчик сигнала становится совсем пустым и атрибут `volatile` исчезает), а просто `gcc ...` (или g++) печатает прямо из обработчика сигнала.

И как обычно, если есть какие-то вопросы -- задавайте в комментарии
(указывая @avp (без собаки нотификация мне не придет))